# Unable to create mount point for ADLS Gen2 in Databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

We are attempting to create a mount point from Azure Databricks to ADLS Gen2 via service principal. The service principal has the appropriate resource level and data level access. The mount point is not being created, though we have confirmed access to ADLS Gen2 is possible via access keys. Azure Databricks VNet injection has been used.

The mount point fails with a non-descript error. There is a firewall which is vetting all traffic from Databricks, so our assumption is that something that is needed for the mount point (an OAuth service or Azure AD API) is being blocked. We have confirmed Databricks can connect to the file system, but the mount point creation using a service principal fails. It is unknown what HTTPS or other services Azure Databricks must be able to contact in order to create the mount point. We believe unlocking what those service endpoints are will enable the creation. Presently, only login.microsoftonline.com is allowed.

```
# Mount point for ADLS Gen2 via. Service principal
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id":  "XXXXXX", 
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "XXXX-scope", key = "XXXX-key"),
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXX/oauth2/token"}

dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://filesystem@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/XXXX",
  extra_configs = configs)


Expect the mount point to be successfully created. Error below:

ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling o220.mount.
: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:259)
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.getTokenSingleCall(AzureADAuthenticator.java:256)
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.getTokenCall(AzureADAuthenticator.java:211)
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.getTokenUsingClientCreds(AzureADAuthenticator.java:94)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.verifyAzureOAuth(DBUtilsCore.scala:477)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.verifyAzureFileSystem(DBUtilsCore.scala:488)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.mount(DBUtilsCore.scala:446)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have provided valid service principal details such as:(appId, password, tenant).

Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 mount configuration:

```
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "<appId>",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": "<password>",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/token",
       "fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization": "true"}

dbutils.fs.mount(
source = "abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/folder1",
mount_point = "/mnt/flightdata",
extra_configs = configs)
```

[image]

Access files in your filesystem as if they were local files:

[image]

**Reference:** [Tutorial: Access Data Lake Storage Gen2 data with Azure Databricks using Spark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-use-databricks-spark)

Hope this helps.